# Visual Studio Code: c/c++ IntelliSense; globbing in includePath?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Does the ([C/C++ plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)) not support globbing in its includePath setting?

I tried:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include",
            "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
            "/usr/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}/**/include"
        ],
... the rest...
```

and it doesn't seem to help.